# How to keep server running on AWS LightSail

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I have a dynamic server hosted by an Ubuntu instance on AWS LightSail that I startup in the shell. It works well but the website no longer works once I close the shell that it is running in.

I am wondering how I can keep my website up with AWS LightSail when I am done using the shell to start the server?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though using `screen -S appname` works.